# Find the Area of a part of a Parellogram

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

ABCD is a parallelogram. P is any point on CD such that $ar(\triangle DPA) = 15 cm^2$
 and $ar(\triangle APC) = 20 cm^2$. Find the area of $ar(\triangle APB)$.

Comment: The police is going to come if you don't edit your post soon...

Comment: pls help in editing

Comment: P cannot be any point on CD if you want those areas. P can only be one point.
So it should say, "P is the point on CD such that DPA = $15 cm^2$ and APC = $20cm^2$

Comment: @AdamRubinson Is it fine now?

Comment: Using the fact that ACD is half the area of the parallelogram, which is the quick way of doing it. If you didn't know this fact, you could instead solve simultaneous equations by doing area of triangles = 1/2 base x width, in order to find the height and width of the parallelogram. Then area of triangle ABP = 1/2 x base (AB) x height. Yeah so this is the same as Sina Babaei Zadeh's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

[image]

I believe that the rest of the problem can be done by you.

Comment: You don't need to solve for any of those variables. Just observe that $[ADC]=[ABC]=[APB]$

Comment: Yes Daniel, it is straightforward to see that triangle ADC = triangle ABC by rules of similar triangles.